# Checking residuals: Forecast -> checkresiduals and bgtest

Tags: r, time-series, arima, forecast

I am using Rob Hyndman's `forecast` package, and I'd like to extract some of the values from the `checkresiduals` function.  Is there a way to call `checkresiduals(model)` and then extract the p-value, lag, and df for the Ljung-Box Test that the function calls?  The function simply prints the output to the console like so:

```
> checkresiduals(arima_model)

    Ljung-Box test

data:  Residuals from ARIMA(0,1,3)(2,0,1)[7]
Q* = 29.221, df = 8, p-value = 0.00029
```

If I were interested instead on running the Breusch-Godfrey Test using the parameters specified by the model that `auto.arima` discovered, would

bgtest(auto.arima(time_series))

be sufficient to specify the correct maximal order and regressors?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both parts of your question relate to how the function `forecast::checkresiduals` actually works. This function is written in pure R, so I would suggest going over the code by just running the `forecast::checkresiduals` command in the console.

For the LB case you can get the p-value like so:

```
arima_model <- forecast::auto.arima(WWWusage)
LBtest <- Box.test(zoo::na.approx(residuals(arima_model))
                   , fitdf = length(arima_model$coef)
                   , lag = max( length(arima_model$coef) + 3
                                , min(10, length(residuals(arima_model))/5) )
                   , type = 'Ljung')

LBtest$p.value
```

The second part of your question has more intricacies and depends on your data and the context of your analysis, but you should be careful in using the `auto.arima` function.

HTH